# Calling javascript function from react native component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Actually I am new to react native, I am calling a javascript function which is in singleton class. I want to call this function from another react native component from constructor.But if I try to call, it is not calling that function.

Code:

```
export default class CustomScreen extends React.Component {
   constructor(){
    LoginUtil.getInstance().getLoginToken() // ==> not working
   }
}
 export default class LoginUtil {

    static instance = null;
    static createInstance() {
        var object = new LoginUtil();
        return object;
    }

    static getInstance () {
        if (!LoginUtil.instance) {
            LoginUtil.instance = LoginUtil.createInstance();
        }
        return LoginUtil.instance;
    }

     getLoginToken(){
        return "token"
    }
  }
```

Comment: Ideally, it should work. Nothing seems wrong in the snippet. What error exactly are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

The way singleton pattern is done in JavaScript is by leveraging exports

Like this:

```
// LoginUtils.js

class LoginUtil {
   
   constructor() {
    // Only called once
     this.token = 'initial';
   }


    setLoginToken(token) {
       this.token = token;
    }

     getLoginToken(){
        return this.token;
    }
  }

export default new LoginUtil();
```

The trick is while exporting the instance, it will handle single instance and avoid writing boilerplate code for instantiating.

Then in your component file do as follow:

```
import loginUtils from './LoginUtils';

export default class CustomScreen extends React.Component {
   constructor(){
    const token = loginUtils.getLoginToken()
   }
}
```

**EDIT:**

The reason your may not work is because you need to add `super()` in your component constructor as first statement:

```
class CustomScreen extends React.Component {
   constructor(){
    super();
    LoginUtil.getInstance().getLoginToken();

   }
   ...
  }
```

```js
class CustomScreen extends React.Component {
   constructor(){
    super()
    this.state = { token: LoginUtil.getInstance().getLoginToken() };

   }
   
   render() {
    return <p>Token: {this.state.token}</p>
   }
}
class LoginUtil {

    static instance = null;
    static createInstance() {
        var object = new LoginUtil();
        return object;
    }

    static getInstance () {
        if (!LoginUtil.instance) {
            LoginUtil.instance = LoginUtil.createInstance();
        }
        return LoginUtil.instance;
    }

     getLoginToken(){
        return "token-test"
    }
  }
  
  ReactDOM.render(<CustomScreen />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of exporting class from the singleton file, export its object like:

```
export default new LoginUtil()
```

Then import this object and call any function of that class